# Convert Jquery Into Pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to convert jquery code in to javascript.

Below Is The Jquery Code which i want to convert into javascript

```
$("textarea").on("keypress", function(e){
    if ( e.which === 13) {
        $(this).val(function(i,v){
            return v + "<br/>";
        });
    }
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/SNeyy/47/

Comment: That's nice. Have fun doing it. So what's your question for us?

Comment: What's the problem you're having with doing that?

Comment: If you are not good in javascript maybe you should learn javascript before learing jQuery.

Comment: @anusnaqvi: Vicky's answer below would work for you. But please be informed that SO generally doesn't appreciate questions like this. You need to show some effort by trying it yourself.

Comment: @Harry shouldn't be saying this, but he probably doesn't care. Every other question on SO is from some guy who wants someone to do this work. I am tired of commenting and trying to point it out to them that this is not the site for them, but there will always be people willing out to help for reputation.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SNeyy/49/)

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    var a = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
    for (i in a) {
        a[i].addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
            if (e.which === 13) {
                this.value = this.value + "<br/>";
            }
        })
    }
}, false);
```